# PHP 5.5 preg_replace using array of patterns returning null

Tags: php, regex

I've looked at other questions on this similar topic, and tried those suggestions but they don't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$badChars = array('/</', '/>/', '/$/', '/\\/', '/=/', '/@/', '/\//');

$cleanData = "Text -with /stuff I don@'t want";

echo $cleanData . "\n";

$cleanData = preg_replace($badChars, '', $cleanData);

echo $cleanData . "\n";

?>
```

Note that the array of patterns will vary based on the scenario.  This is for a data cleansing exercise.  e.g.: if processing an email field, we'd temporarily drop the @ pattern.

And this is the output:

```
Text -with /stuff I don@'t want

PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '/' found in /home/tim/xm_code/symphony/code/components/controllers/test.php on line 9

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I can't find anything to help me resolve this.  Any ideas?

Comment: @chris85 - forgot to say i need to be able to remove or add elements from the array of patterns depending on the scenario.

Comment: Still should be able to use the `str_replace` unless you are doing something more advanced then replacing single characters. e.g. you'll have the same replace array just remove/add whatever you want to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your double backslash is escaping your closing delimiter. So

```
'/\\/'
```

needs to be

```
'/\\\/'
```

Alternatively use a character class and you don't need the array. Second alternative, use `str_replace` since the characters are all static.

```
$badChars = array('<', '>', '$', '\\', '=', '@', '/');
$cleanData = "Text -with /stuff I don@'t want";
echo $cleanData . "\n";
$cleanData = str_replace($badChars, '', $cleanData);
```